# In C#, What happens with a TransactionScope if an error occurs inside the transaction

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering what happens with a transactionscope in C# when an error occurs in a try-catch inside the transaction, and the error is handled inside the transaction?

Example code:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // do some work
    try
    {
        // do some work that may fail
    }
    catch
    {
       // gracefully handle the error
    }
    
    // continue work

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Is the transaction rolled back when the error occurs, even though it is handled in the catch block?

If it rolls back, could I wrap the code in the try-catch block in a second transactionscope with TransactionScopeOption.Suppress to prevent the rollback?

Comment: `TransactionScope` does not alter the scope of block statement blocks. There's no magic here. The catch is specified to catch all exceptions thus no error raised in the proceeding try block would terminate the method and thus any statements following the catch will execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because You put the transaction.Complete(); at the end, it will be confirmed in any case.
It is better to change the code as below so that the rollback is done correctly

```
try
{
   using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
   {
      // do some work
       transaction.Complete();
   }
}
catch
{
   // continue work
}
```

[implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope#rolling-back-a-transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope#rolling-back-a-transaction)

Comment: Yes that is my usual implementation when using transactionscope. It seems errors throw and handled within the scope do not rollback the transaction.